# Objective c How to set orientation to landscape in ios13

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My code is working on the versions except 13. But in the version 13, the code doesn't work for landscape of orientation. 
My code is following.

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#else
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#endif
{
    NSLog(@"Mask Orientaion begin");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    NSLog(@"Orientaion begin");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ios 13, default modalpresentaionstyle is 'fromsheet', not 'fullscreen' not like the previous versions. You should set the modalpresentaionstyle of the controller to 'UImodalPresentaionFullscreen' like "control.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;".